# How to store complex data into an array using a For loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am trying to store data that contains complex numbers into an array. I am having issues on how to setup the loop and extract the data. The error I am getting says "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals" which is in code line 11.

```
for k=10e-10:0.01:10  %discrete reduced frequency range
Ck = (besselh(1,2,k))./(besselh(1,2,k)+1i*besselh(0,2,k)); %Bessel function

%Matrices
A=[0.8132  -0.1008; -0.0725  2.0518]; 
B=Ck*[7.623  57.15; -8.233  -57.157]; 
C=Ck*[1865  1473.14; -1119  11907.48]; 

%frd function
Hresp=frd(Abar,k);
H11(k)=Hresp;
end
```

I would like my output data to look like the image below:
[image: I would like my output data to look like this]

Comment: You failed to specify what the issue actually is. I am guessing that you are getting a complain about a non-integer index from `H11(k)`.

Comment: Thanks, I will include that. & Yes, that is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way (IMO) to do what you want is to have an integer loop index, and a pre-computed array with `k` values:

```
k = 10e-10:0.01:10;
H11 = zeros(size(k));
for ii = 1:numel(k)
  H11(ii) = k(ii); % whatever computation here involving k(ii)
end
```

Note that I pre-allocated `H11`, this prevents re-allocation during the loop execution.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `k` is a non-integer and you are trying to index with it. There is no `0.1` element of an array, only elements `1`, `2`, `3`, ... Use a separate variable to keep track of what index you are on. For instance,

```
ind = 1;
for k = 10e-10 : 0.01 : 10
  % some work would go here
  H11(ind) = whatever;
  ind = ind + 1;
end
```

Comment: This does not work with the `frd` function... it complains "subscripted assignment dimension mismatch"

Comment: @Jesus you still got to write `k=10e-10:0.01:10` instead of `k = 0 : 0.1 : 10`